# Change value for all keys with jq

Tags: json, jq, key-value

I have this package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "eslint": "^7.15.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  } 
}
```

with this command :

```
jq '.dependencies.eslint="latest"|.dependencies.express="latest"' package.json
```

I got this result :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "eslint": "latest",
    "express": "latest"
  }
}
```

How can I change all versions to "latest" without enumerating individual keys ?

Comment: Is `body-parser` supposed to be made latest or not? If you only want a subset of items in the `dependencies` object to change, you're stuck telling jq exactly which those are.

Comment: I want to change all versions including `body-parser`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
jq '.dependencies[]="latest"' package.json
```

Output:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "latest",
    "eslint": "latest",
    "express": "latest"
  }
}
```

Comment: I do have other keys, but `[]=` seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Ok, I will never understand `jq` :) (removed it from the answer)

Answer (score 3):

A succinct, precise, and easy-to-read solution:

```
.dependencies |= map_values("latest")
```

Comment: Hi @peak, now I have two ADDITIONAL OPTIONAL keys : devDependencies and resolutions. I know I can do `.dependencies |= map_values("latest") | .devDependencies |= map_values("latest") | .resolutions |= map_values("latest")`. How can I make a generic solution ? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “generic” here. Maybe it would be best if you asked a new SO q. accordingly.

Comment: I just want to avoid repeating the same structure 3 times.

Comment: So write a suitable `def`.

Answer (score 2):

if `package.json` by chance contains nested items, like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "eslint": "^7.15.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "branch": {
        "alternative": "^1.2.3"
    }
  } 
}
```

then an alternative (non-jq) solution, using `jtc` would look like this:

```
<package.json jtc -w'<>a:' -u'"latest"'
```

- that solution won't break the original JSON structure.

PS. I'm the developer of `jtc` unix JSON processor.
PPS. the disclaimer is required by SO.

Comment: thanks! comments like this fuel me for further development of my tools :)))